# hadoop 3.3.1 'get command' does not return cZxid,ctime,mZxid

Tags: apache-zookeeper

hadoop 3.3.1
I have created Znode 'FirstZnode'

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 1] create /FirstZnode Myfirstzookeeper-app
Created /FirstZnode
```

while when I run 'get /FirstZnode',it only returns 'Myfirstzookeeper-app'

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 11] get /FirstZnode
Myfirstzookeeper-app
```

anybody knows why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `-s` to show the stat:

```
get -s /FirstZnode
```